# How to get the Tkinter widget calling a function with "bind"

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I am developing a tool in Python with an interface and I have several elements of this interface that are generated automatically (several Comboboxes with the same elements in them are generated in a for loop) and I would like to make sure that when an element is selected in a Combobox, it disappears from the others.

For that I thought of using the "bind" function but I don't know how to retrieve the Combobox that called this function.

Basically, I would need to know which Combobox has been modified when the callback function is called

Do you know how to do that?

Thanks

PS : Code looks like this :

````
for test_name in ["idvg0", "idvgh", "idvd0", "idvdh", "acvg0", "acvgh", "acfreq0", "noise"]:
        test_frame = Frame(notebook, name=test_name+"_frame")
        notebook.add(test_frame, text=test_name)
        name_frame = Frame(test_frame)
        name_frame.pack(side=TOP, expand = 1, fill=X)
        name_label = Label(name_frame, text="Name")
        name_label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20)
        name_entry = Entry(name_frame, text=test_name)
        name_entry.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X, padx=10)
        type_frame = Frame(test_frame)
        type_frame.pack(side=TOP, expand=1, fill=X)
        type_label = Label(type_frame, text="Type")
        type_label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20)
        type_var = IntVar()
        dc_type_radio = Radiobutton(type_frame, text="DC", variable=type_var, value=1)
        dc_type_radio.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
        ac_type_radio = Radiobutton(type_frame, text="AC", variable=type_var, value=2)
        ac_type_radio.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
        acfreq_type_radio = Radiobutton(type_frame, text="ACFREQ", variable=type_var, value=3)
        acfreq_type_radio.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
        noise_type_radio = Radiobutton(type_frame, text="Noise", variable=type_var, value=4)
        noise_type_radio.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
        nodes_frame = Frame(test_frame, name="nodes_frame")
        nodes_frame.pack(side=TOP, expand = 1, fill=X)
        for node in ["d", "g", "s", "b"]:
            node_frame = Frame(nodes_frame, name=node+"_frame")
            node_frame.pack(side=TOP, expand = 1, fill=X, pady=20)
            node_name_label = Label(node_frame, text="Node " + node)
            node_name_label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20)
            type_label = Label(node_frame, text="Type")
            type_label.pack(side=LEFT)
            type_list = ttk.Combobox(node_frame, values=["List","Sweep","Constant"], name="type_list")
            type_list.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)
            type_list.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", change_node_type)```
````

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `event.widget`?

Comment: Yes, that's it ! Thank you very much